# Vertical Column Dividers are discontinuous in a table

Tags: tables

I am a beginner in latex. I want to draw a table in latex. But, unfortunately, the last vertical lines are discontinuous. Is there a way to fix it?

**Latex Code:**

```
\begin{tabular}{||c||c||}
    \hline \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{Duration of course} & Month/Year - Month/Year\\[0.1cm] \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{No. of credits} & $\#$ of credits\\[0.1cm] \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{Course Slot} & slot letter allocated to the course, if slotting system is followed\\[0.1cm] \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{Course Timings} & Day: Time slot\\[0.1cm] \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{Evaluation Pattern} & Evaluation Pattern and Weightage\\[0.1cm] \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{TAs} & Name of TA, Designation, Roll no:\\[0.1cm] \hline \\[-0.2cm]
    \textbf{Course Overview} & Overview of the course\\[0.1cm] \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: this must be a duplicate  but `\hline\\[-0.2cm]` makes a row with just one cell, so only lines from that cell, you could use `\hline&\\ ` to make a full blank row, but using a blank row and then negative spacing to over-print that is almost always going to be the wrong thing to do so just use `\hline` not `\hline\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! It worked! I used negative spacing to give the cells a centered-alignment.

Comment: it's a bad idea, it to use negative spacing, it causes the rules to over-print (which can cause some artefacts) but to see it really go wrong try `\begin{tabular}{||c@{ --- }c||}` for example.